# Commands doen't work because of the Address module and its dependencies

Tags: 8, console

When I try to use a Drupal Console command, even a simple a `drupal list`, I get an error.

> Fatal error: Class 'CommerceGuys\Addressing\AddressFormat\AddressFormatRepository' not found in /path/to/my_project/web/modules/contrib/address/src/Repository/AddressFormatRepository.php on line 16

Of course, the last AddressFormatRepository extends the other and has
`use CommerceGuys\Addressing\AddressFormat\AddressFormatRepository as ExternalAddressFormatRepository;`.

The namespace is good, classes exist, so I don't understand why I get the error.

The composer.json file contains the following lines.

```
"drupal/address": "~1.0",     
"drupal/console": "^1.0.2",    
"drupal/core": "^8.6.0",
```

I tried to update the Address module, manually install the dependencies with Composer, but nothing changed.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Have you tried `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Yes I tried, but nothing more. I think composer install/update do it automatically ?

Comment: Yeah it does, but sometimes things get out of sync. Always worth a try at least